# Android button invisible not working

Tags: android, button, invisible

I tried to make a button invisible, but its not working as expected.

Based on condition, I have added the animation to the buttons, modifying the text in the buttons and I need to make one button invisible. I am setting it to INVISIBLE and the code is getting executed. But, its not getting invisible. I can still see the button on the screen.

What might be the reason?

Sorry for not pasting the code.

I am sure the code is getting executed as expected. But, button is not getting invisible.

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the code, it should work as expected if written properly.

Comment: Please post the code. Without it we are helpless. Its hard to guess your problem.

Comment: I think you are creating reference to the Button in onCreate() and you are trying to make it invisible in some other inner class. Try to make Button as a class field.

Comment: What kind of device are you using for testing ? I am on a Samsung Device, and facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set button visibility to GONE (button will be completely removed; the buttons space will be available for another widgets) or INVISIBLE (button will became transparent; its space will not be available for another widgets):

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or in xml:

```
<Button ...
 android:visibility="gone"/>
```

Comment: I tried this also, But no use. I am facing same problem  again and again. If i have less work in the swipe event, it works as expected. I have swipe event, while will trigger a sound, modify the button text and adds animation to button, followed by making one button invisible. This invisible or gone step is not working.